# set label font from a qt embedded resource font in pyside

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I want to set a label font in my pyside python file to an embedded font in a resource file.
I added font to a qt qrc file, compiled it will rcc and no I want to use it.

Searching internet I realized i should use some thing like:

```
fontDatabase=QtGui.QFontDatabase()
fontDatabase.addApplicationFont(":/new/prefix1/FONT.TTF");
```

But how to apply this fontDatabase to my pushbutton label?

Comment: Just import your `.qrc` file and then run it, it should work.

Comment: no i convert qrc file to py file and import it has no effect on fonts